# Maven unable to download dependencies even after setting proxy

Tags: maven

I am using my company's machine. To connect to internet I will use proxy. The same proxy is working good to browse in ie chrome and firefox. i put the same proxy address in maven settings.xml. But it is not working for maven. It is showing as unknown host. I configured my username password host and port in settings.xml. but still it is showing as unknown host? Is it not possible to use this proxy? Can someone please help me

Comment: It would help to have the full error message here...and yes proxies are working with Maven...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise.. thanks for ur rly.. I m getting the error as Failed to collect dependencies: http://proxy.xyz.com/gateway.pac . Unknown host http://proxy.xyz.com/gateway.pac

Comment: This is the generic error i m getting. I am using the same host under Lan settings/address for IE. It is working

Comment: What do your `settings.xml` and `pom.xml` look like?